# Relacionando vários dados de uma tabela à um dado de outra com SQL

Tags: sql, relacionamento

Precisei listar, com SQL, o pai, a mãe e o cônjuge de uma pessoa junto com seus dados gerais (Ex.: nome, endereco, telefone, email, pai, mae, conjuge, status).

Esses dados estão em outra tabela chamada dependente, cada um relacionado ao id da pessoa

Num primeiro momento achei que fosse bem complicado, cheguei a fazer buscas na internet, inclusive aqui, sem resultado, daí resolvi queimar mais um pouco o cérebro, e cheguei a uma solução super simples que supriu minha necessidade:

```
SELECT
    p.nome,
    p.endereco,
    p.telefone,
    p.email,
    dp.nome AS nomePai,
    dm.nome AS nomeMae,
    dc.nome AS conjuge,
    p.status,
FROM
    pessoa p
    JOIN dependente dp ON dp.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dp.tipo = 6
    JOIN dependente dm ON dm.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dm.tipo = 7
    JOIN dependente dc ON dc.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dc.tipo = 5
```

Quem souber de uma maneira melhor é só colocar aí nos comentários e ajudar a comunidade

Comment: E qual é exatamente sua dúvida?

Comment: Não é dúvida, eu quis só compartilhar uma solução de um problema

Comment: Essa query não tem muito mistério... é assim mesmo.

Comment: @IsaiasLima você pode fazer o seguinte: explica um pouco melhor quais foram os problemas que você enfrentou e postar a solução (utilizar alias e múltiplos joins para a mesma tabela) como resposta.

Comment: A ideia é que alguém faça como você: pesquise sobre determinado problema no google ou aqui e encontre a sua solução.

Comment: Apenas observe que tem uma *virgula* sobrando no fim dos seus campos de *select* que pode causar erro na execução da query.

Comment: É... essa vírgula foi displicência na hora de colocar aqui no site :)

Answer (score 2):

Algumas coisas que podem ser melhoradas:

## Explicitar junção fraca (`left outer join`)

Isto especifica que você está admitindo que nem sempre os dados existem, o que pode acontecer. Por exemplo, uma pessoa solteira não tem cônjuge. `JOIN`, por padrão, é um `INNER JOIN`. Não existindo algum dos registros, a linha pode vir nula.

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` garante que a linha existente em `PESSOA` sempre virá, mesmo que as outras não existam.

```
SELECT
    p.nome,
    p.endereco,
    p.telefone,
    p.email,
    dp.nome AS nomePai,
    dm.nome AS nomeMae,
    dc.nome AS conjuge,
    p.status,
FROM
    pessoa p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dependente dp ON dp.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dp.tipo = 6
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dependente dm ON dm.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dm.tipo = 7
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dependente dc ON dc.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dc.tipo = 5
```

## Sendo apenas uma coluna, *subselects* podem ter desempenho superior

Isto na verdade depende da tecnologia do seu banco de dados. Recomendo um estudo do plano de execução para avaliar o custo de ambas.

Sua sentença pode ser escrita assim:

```
SELECT
    p.nome,
    p.endereco,
    p.telefone,
    p.email,
    (SELECT dp.nome FROM dependente dp WHERE dp.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dp.tipo = 6) AS nomePai,
    (SELECT dm.nome FROM dependente dm WHERE dm.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dm.tipo = 7) AS nomeMae,
    (SELECT dc.nome FROM dependente dc WHERE dc.idPessoa = p.idPessoa AND dc.tipo = 5) AS conjuge,
    p.status,
FROM
    pessoa p
```